# How did inmates escape through the sea in Prison Break

Tags: realism, prison-break

In the episode *HELL OR HIGH WATER* on *Prison Break*, how did the inmates that escape from Sona breathe under the water and make it through the sea?

I mean what is that device they used under the water?

Answer (score 2):

They used miniature SCUBA gear, specifically, hand refillable oxygen bottles.

> Most snorkels will allow you to swim underwater for around two minutes before you have to surface to gasp for air.
>
> But a new snorkel-style gadget means swimmers can take even longer to explore the deep.
>
> The Scorkl holds enough air to let you breathe underwater for up to 10 minutes, and can be reused time and time again, simply by being pumped up.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-4599134/Snorkel-lets-swimmers-breathe-underwater-10-MINUTES.html)</sup>

I don't have a screen capture from the TV series but devices look **incredibly** similar to these...

[image]